# How to get parent id on parent and also on the children elements click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code as follows:

```
<div id="make" data-make-unique-id="{{ values.unique_id }}">
     <div class="d-flex flew-row align-items-center">
          <i class="icon-{{ key|lower }}" style="font-size: 19px;"></i>
          <div class="text-capitalize">{{ key|lower }}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="d-flex align-items-center">{{ values.counter }}</div>
</div>
```

I want to capture **click** event on the div with id `make`. And I want to get `data-make-unique-id` tag value, no matter if is clicked on the div with id make or on some of the children.

I tried something as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '#make', (e) => {                
    const unique_id = $(this).data("make-unique-id");
    debugger;
});
```

But if it doesn't work.

Comment: You have been provided with two working answers if they don't work I suspect that your CSS is interfering, do you have any console errors?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#make', (e) => {                
    const unique_id = $(e.target).data("make-unique-id");
    debugger;
});` but if #make is not dynamic, just use `$("#make").on("click",function() {  const unique_id = $(this).data("make-unique-id"); });` - note the difference between (e) => and function()

Comment: `this` context is different in the provided scope.. If not, are you looking for jQuery [attribute=value] Selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you :-

```
$("#make").on("click", function(event){
  var unique_id = $(this).data("make-unique-id");
});
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that it's all about `function` versus `() => {}`. The latter does not create new context and therefore `$(this)` is not what OP expect

Comment: Yes agree'd not sure why the two valid answers to this question are being down voted though.

Answer (score 1):

Add the click listener on the element with id 'make'. And also if you want to bind `this` then use normal function instead of arrow function.

See below the sample code.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#make').click(function() {
        const unique_id = $(this).data("make-unique-id");
        console.log(unique_id);
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="make" data-make-unique-id="2">
        <div class="d-flex flew-row align-items-center">
            <i class="icon-{{ key|lower }}" style="font-size: 19px;"></i>
            <div class="text-capitalize">{{ key|lower }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">{{ values.counter }}</div>
    </div>
```

Hope this will solve the issue.